# Is it possible to create a grid-like background in CSS without images or tables?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'd like to create a background that looks something like an excel spreadsheet. White table cells, thin borders around each cell. I know how to do this easily with a single image, and I know how to do this with tables...but I would like to do this without either, if possible.

The size of each cell will be fixed at 20x20, so I don't have to worry about resizing. Any thoughts? I sort of had a way cooked up that involved a ton of inner markup, but I figured that was almost as bad as using a table.

The purpose of this background will be allowing users to arrange blocks on a grid. Using jQuery UI's drag and drop functionality, I want the user to be able to move blocks around within a confined grid. The gridlines would simply show them where in the grid their blocks are bound to. An example of this grid snapping (without the gridlines) is available at http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#snap-to

Comment: If this is strictly for a background you should use an image.. if the cells will be holding tabular data.. you should use a table.

Comment: What's the point of the background? Are you going to put data inside these cells? It's considered correct to use tables for tabular data.

Comment: You can do it with a css gradient and multiple backgrounds, but browser support isn't amazing, an image is really your best bet here.

Answer (score 28):

I have searched also for this problem and i found a [very good solution](http://jsfiddle.net/2kmUg/1/):

```
background-size: 40px 40px;    
background-size: 40px 40px;    
background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(0deg, #fff, #fff 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 40px),repeating-linear-gradient(-90deg, #fff, #fff 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 40px);
```

```css
body {
    background:#000;
    z-index:-5;
}

#lines {
    background-size: 40px 40px;    
    background-image:repeating-linear-gradient(0deg, #fff, #fff 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 40px),repeating-linear-gradient(-90deg, #fff, #fff 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 40px);
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    opacity:0.14;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:-4;
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay"></div>
<div id="lines"></div>
```

To change the grid size, change the background-size and the last px option within the gradient.
To change the grid width change the first px option within the gradient.
First gradient is horizontal, second is for the vertical lines.

for this demo I recognized that the css option:

```
position: absolute
```

was required. I will build up my grid now and if I get more information I will add them within a comment.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Googlers: if you need the grid to precisely align the foreground items, the good news is the grid won't add to the content width like the regular `border` does. But make sure to use `background-position-x: .5px; background-position-y: .5px;` to align those grid lines.

Answer (score 12):

Use a background image; don't waste your time fiddling with markup.  You're not going to get any more efficient than this:

```
background:url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhFAAUAIAAAMDAwP///yH5BAEAAAEALAAAAAAUABQAAAImhI+pwe3vAJxQ0hssnnq/7jVgmJGfGaGiyoyh68GbjNGXTeEcGxQAOw==);
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/josh3736/p77S3/).

Comment: That looks awesome but how to define the square size (with a parameter) or even choose another colour? Thanks!

Comment: @RuiMarques: Make another image.  There are [tools](http://dopiaza.org/tools/datauri/) that generate data URIs for you.

Comment: @josh3736 yes but I would like create the image dynamically so I will need the javascript code to do it. I already found a way but it requires HTML5 canvas, I wanted to somehow avoid needing it.

Comment: Something like this, but this is more complex (powerfull) than what i need ahahah: http://www.xarg.org/2010/03/generate-client-side-png-files-using-javascript/

Comment: This won't work if I need a 1mm×1mm grid because of varying screen DPIs, correct?